# View error pods which is above 5 days only

Tags: kubernetes, devops

I need to get error pods above five days.
The below commands is working well for the pods which is below five days. Could anyone please let me know on how to get pods which is above 5 days only. It should not show the error pods which is below 5 days.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | awk 'match($6,/^[1-4]d|^[1-900]+h|^[1-900]+m|^[1-900]+s/) {print $0}' | grep "Error"
```

Comment: So you want to list pods older than 5 days or created within 5 days?

Comment: I want older than 5 days.

Comment: Could you try this: `kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}} {{.metadata.creationTimestamp}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | awk '$2 <= "'$(date -d'now-5 days' -Ins --utc | sed 's/+0000/Z/')'" { print $1 }' | grep "Error"`? It works for me but I can't check the `| grep "Error"` part as I don't have such pods right now.

Comment: It is showing only pod name and if I change print from $1 to $0 ( { print $0 }')  its not showing all the columns. Could you please let me know command to get all columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got two options for you:

```
kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | awk 'match($5,/[6-9]d|[0-9][0-9]d|[0-9][0-9][0-9]d/) {print $0}' | grep -i error
```

or

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Pending --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | awk 'match($5,/[6-9]d|[0-9][0-9]d|[0-9][0-9][0-9]d/) {print $0}'
```

Both will only show pods that exists for 6 days or longer. First option will also look for those with errors and the second one will show only those with the `Status=Pending`.